# How to show an image in video player

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I want to show image in player but I can't, My player is:

```
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="250" height="200"
                                    poster="{{ public_path().'/content/video/title.jpg' }}"
                                    data-setup="{}">
                                <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
         </video>
```

I have the image title.jpg in fmti\public\content\video.
But I get the error :

```
404 Not Found - http://fmti.md:8000/home/vagrant/Workspace/fmti/public/content/video/title.jpg"
```

So the image exist in this folder, I can't understand where is my error.
Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: Please add the error, the link is broken.

Comment: downvoted. It has nothing to do with php or laravel. and tagging all versions of laravel is not acceptable since they are totally different by structure, code and base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public_path()` is for the system path to the `public` directory and is meant to be used when doing file operations inside your application. The client however can't use an absolute system path that includes the `home` directory etc.
What you want to use instead is the `asset()` function:

```
poster="{{ asset('content/video/title.jpg') }}"
```

This will generate an URI that's actually accessible by the browser.